# ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

How can I resolve the following issue without installing CUDA 9.0?

I have installed CUDA 9.2
machine: Windows 10 64 bit
Nvidia driver 398.11
Python 3.6.5
Tensorflow

Im unable to import tensorflow as I get the following error. Please help to resolve.

> ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires
>   that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
>   environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL:
>   https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: Simply install CUDA 9.0

Comment: There is no way to resolve this except to install CUDA 9.0

Comment: You can download the CUDA 9.0 toolkit here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal